# How to show username on each page of app,fetching it from a textfield on login page?

Tags: ios, authentication

I want to show the username,of the user logged into the app from the login page/view, on all the views of the app. The code of the login page having two textfields and a button is shown below:

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    if ([txtUser.text length] == 0 || [txtPass.text length]== 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Kindly enter details in all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [database open];

    BOOL success = NO;

    NSInteger count = [database intForQuery:@"select count(*) from RegMembers where     USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?", txtUser.text, txtPass.text];
}
```

Comment: What's your question? u have plenty ways to implement that... NSUserDefaults, Static variable, Singelton, Static Object, and many more...

Comment: @gran33 my question is that i want to show the "username",of a particular user,logged into the app, on each viewcontroller in the app.i am new to iOS programming so need a detailed code explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a single character you can use appDelegate to store the value and access it in all the view controllers. If you have more than one data, its better to use a singleton class

Just use

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

EDIT : adding details about using appdelegate

In AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *username;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize username;
```

In your LoginViewController.h, import the AppDelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

In your LoginViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //Do other stuff
}
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    if ([txtUser.text length] == 0 || [txtPass.text length]== 0){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Kindly enter details in all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        appDelegate.username = txtUser.text;
    }


   [database open];

   BOOL success = NO;

   NSInteger count = [database intForQuery:@"select count(*) from RegMembers where     USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?", txtUser.text, txtPass.text];
}
```

In anyOtherViewController where you want to access it, do the following in its .h file

```
import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AnyOtherViewController : UIViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

And in it's .m file do the following

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 NSLog (@"%@",appDelegate.username);
}
```

You access the username using

```
appDelegate.username;
```

EDIT 2: Displaying username

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 0, 70, 30)]; 
    [label setText:appDelegate.username]; 
    [self.view addSubview : label];
}
```

Add the above code in the view controllers and you can see the username on the top rightside of that view controller when you run the app.

Comment: no it's multi character username,o can you explain the singleton solution.

Comment: isn't it a single NSString?
Do you have multiple data to store like name,username, password etc?

Comment: i've stored username,password in a table in database,but that's a different thing,right now i just want to show the username of a user who is logged into the app,on each page of app.by either fetching it from database or from the textfield of the login page.

Comment: logically your answer hits the bulls eye and i expected it to run but unfortunately it didnt,as the output on console shows "null" as result of nslog statements,and secondly i want to show the exact username entered into the textfield on the login viewcontroller on every viewcontroller,ANYWHERE.am i doing something wrong?

Comment: dear ,it dosent help until you get results visible in your app,which isnt the case yet,but i guess if you can dig it deeper it will resolve the issue.as i just want to show the name of the user who's logged in on each view.so that i can use that text further in my app.

Comment: i am able to show the entered username into the console,as output of nslog statements,but no change in the view controllers(the username isnt shown on any view controller).

Comment: just add a label in the view controller and set its text to appDelegate.username......      

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 0, 70, 30)];
    [label setText:appDelegate.username];
    [self.view addSubview : label];

Add the above code to - (void) viewDidLoad {} of the viewcontrollers you want to show the username. the username will be shown at the top right corner of your app screen

Comment: dear a white rectangle is shown on the view controller after implementing your code,but the text of the username isnt displayed in that space.for your info. let me tell you that the nest view is a table view and i've added background color to that(if that's what stopping the code from working!).but none the less great idea to resolve my issue,i am sure you'll sort it out soon.

Comment: hey bro,i am stuck at this issue,after your solution,kindly have a look at my previous comment and help reolve the issue,o that i can mark your answer as the right one.thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: did you store the username to the appdelegate from the loginViewController?.......... 
`appDelegate.username = txtUser.text;`

Comment: also you should add `appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` in LoginViewController.m 's viewDidLoad()

Comment: i already added "appDelegate" in LoginViewController.m's viewdidload,and my LoginViewController.m's and other file's code is the same as you pasted above before a few days.still a white rectangle appears not the text on the tableview.

Comment: you have a github account?? share your code with me .. aravindgs007@gmail.com

Comment: bro i am waiting for your answer.about the email i sent you.

Comment: was a bit busy for the last two days. will get back to you soon with the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NSUserDefaults**

To Save:

```
-(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
    if(yourConditions)
    {
        ...
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setValue:self.txtLoginName.text forKey:@"loginName"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

To Retrieve:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *str = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"loginName"];    
}
```

Developer Guid of NSUserDefaults: [https://developer.apple.com...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborative,i mean i tried to type your code in my app but it didnt work.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Database.You can save it in a seperate table.

Or

save as a variable [NSString] in appdelgate and use it anywhere

OR

[NSUserdefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: can you explain your suggestions in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Best Practise is to inherit UIViewController and have your own parent view controller
.h
    @interface UIMainViewController : UIViewController  {

```
}

@property(nonatomic,strong) UITextField *loggedInUsernameTextField;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation UIMainViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

            [super viewDidLoad];
            _loggedInUsernameTextField = @"Whatever name";
    }
@end
```